# CAKeyframeAnimation with path; can the path be extended to extend the animation?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

You would be familiar with the games where a train moves slowly along a track that is made from puzzle pieces - if you can't tile more pieces onto the track the train crashes and you lose. One way to do this would be to make the train follow a path defined in a CAKeyframeAnimation.

Once the animation is created and added to the layer can you extend the path? (Maybe by maintaining a hold on the CGPathRef and adding to it) Or do you need to create a new path and new animation and replace the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - the animation proceeds along the path with appended paths just fine. Now that problem is solved the new problem is [how to make animation progress according to touch inputs, not elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4720122/189804).