# iPhone animation based on input values (touches) not time

Tags: iphone, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

For an animation effect perfectly suited to an animation group approach as shown in [Brad Larson's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path/1143095#1143095), I need the animation to proceed according to inputs. Specifically touch and position of detected touches. It is easy to handle touchesMoved: and to set the position of the elements for every touch but it just isn't smooth like the core animation approach.

Imagine a marble in a grooved track. I want to push the marble along to any position at any speed in one direction or the other. The animation has to do something like that, moving a visual element along a path in response to touches. CAKeyframeAnimation has the path bit exactly but seems to always want to base the transition from frame to frame on time elapsed, not on any other factor, and in one direction.

31 January update - Thanks all for the responses so far however none is really solving the problem. I have a circular menu that is dragged to select an option. All of it needs to move together and I have worked around it by using an view that has a rotational transform applied and the inverse rotational transform applied to its subviews so the icons all rotate with appropriate ferris wheel orientation. It really looks better when the icons are animated along a slightly ovoid path though... the marble description is an attempt to make clear what I'm trying to do. Better perhaps to imagine magnets oriented to repel all travelling in a groove - move one and its neighbours move too but not necessarily in the direction that the dragged magnet moves as the path curves.

Right now the problem is one of following a simple path created with one circle but I'd really like to know how to animate objects along an arbitrary path, position controlled purely by touch with no calculations involving velocity or direction.

Comment: Hmm, this became a popular question. Pivot's answer is correct and has worked well for me in code written since the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be able to use the [hierarchical nature of timelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html) in layer trees to achieve what you’re looking for. Objects implementing [`CAMediaTiming`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html), which include both `CAAnimation` and `CALayer`, inherit a timespace from their parent, which they can modify (via scaling, shifting and repeating) and propagate to their children. By setting the `speed` property of a layer to 0.0 and adjusting the `timeOffset` property manually, you can decouple that layer (and all of its sublayers) from the usual notion of time.

What you’d do in your case is define the animations for all your menu items to animate their position along your desired `CGPath` from time *t*<sub>0</sub> to *t*<sub>1</sub>, with the appropriate `timeOffset` on each animation to keep your items appropriately spaced. Note that a `beginTime` of 0.0 on an animation is usually interpreted as starting from the time the animation was added to its layer, so if you want *t*<sub>0</sub> to be 0.0, you'll probably have to set it to a tiny epsilon > 0.0.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.beginTime = 1e-100;
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.path = path;
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
animation.timeOffset = timeOffset;
```

You’d then set the `speed` property to 0.0 on a parent layer (containing only these menu items) and update its `timeOffset` to values between *t*<sub>0</sub> and *t*<sub>1</sub> in response to your touch events.

This approach has two potential caveats. Because you’ve taken over the nature of time on this layer subtree, you probably won’t be able to animate other properties at the same time. Additionally, if you want coasting behavior for a fast flick, you’ll probably need to animate time forward on your own.

Comment: Great idea! I'm accepting it since it's going to give the level of control I need even if it is not exactly binding animation to touch position. It should be possible to manipulate timeOffset to make it very close to the same thing.

Comment: If the relationship between touch position and animation progress is linear, you could just choose the animations’ beginTime and duration such that you can pass the relevant component of your touch position as timeOffset and have Core Animation’s time-to-progress mapping apply that relationship for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS 4.0 or greater then you can use the [new block based class methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) to start animatable changes to [view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) objects. So from your touch event you can initiate an animatable change to properties on the view:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    yourView.alpha = 0.0; // fade out yourView over 1 second
}];
```

**N.B.** This could just as easily be a change to another property on the view, like its location.  You can animate the following properties on the view this way:

```
@property frame
@property bounds
@property center
@property transform
@property alpha
@property backgroundColor
@property contentStretch
```

If you are targetting earlier versions of iOS you will need to use UIView [beginAnimations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations%3acontext%3a) and [commitAnimations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/commitAnimations) methods to create an animation block:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; 
yourView.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This stuff works really well and once you start using it, you will have to be careful you don't get addicted. ;)

**Update for comment:**

You can bind the position of the marble to the location of the touch event. Once you get the [touchesEnded](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesEnded%3awithEvent%3a) event you can then animate the location of the marble using an animation block.

Comment: Yes but the problem is I don't want to have anything to do with duration. Think of the marble. If I do nothing to it, it does nothing. If I push it slowly then it moves slowly, if fast then it moves fast. If I stop pushing it suddenly after moving it fast it should keep rolling a while until it slows and stops. Seems like the time approach doesn't allow this. I do have some beautiful smooth animation happening with CAKeyframeAnimation, but I can't control it other than to set it running and to set ease in/ease out.

Comment: There's still a problem. The position of the objects are not the position of the touch, they have to stay in a path. The stroke of the touch just imparts motion to the objects when the touches happen in the right view. The objects must follow a path. Also calculating the position and doing this the obvious way just isn't smooth enough especially when the position calculation gets expensive or on older iOS devices.

Comment: @adam-eberbach Ah! I see your point. It is the interpolation between touche events that is causing issues. I'll have a think about that. Definitely non-trivial :)

Answer (score 1):

velocity = distance/time. You can try by giving delay according to touches moved and time. You can calculate time between touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain I understand exactly what you want to do but... Why not just draw the marble wherever the user's finger is? No animation required.
If you want to keep the marble moving after the user lets go, you need to maintain a concept of momentum and use that to animate the marble slowing down. You could use either CoreAnimation for that or a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a velocity calculation in touches moved, and add it to a local variable that a block can mutate via a timer.

in other words, in touches moved  make a velocity calculation bearing in mind the direction of a previous velocity. In touches ended, fire a block that translates the 'marble' decaying the velocity as you disire. If the user moves the marble again, modify the local variable, this will in turn speed up the animation of the marble or slow it down/change direction depending on on the direction of the touch.